# Question about using while loop instead of for in STL list, and function object C++

Tags: c++

everyone.
I have a question about using the while loop instead of for iterator for my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list> 
#include <iterator> 

using namespace std;


class Okreni 
{ 
public: 
    list<int> operator () (list <int> g) const { 
        list<int> :: iterator it1 = g.begin();
        list<int> :: iterator it2 = --g.end();
        list<int> :: iterator sredina = g.begin();
        advance(sredina, (distance(it1,it2))/2);
        for(it1; it1 != sredina; it1++){

            swap(*it1, *it2);

            it2--;
        }
        if(distance(it1,it2)%2!=0){
            swap(*it1,*it2);
        }
        return g;
    } 
}; 

void ispis(list <int> g){
    list <int> :: iterator it; 
    for(it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); it++) 
        cout << *it << " " ; 
    cout << endl; 
}

list<int> zamijeni(list <int> g){
    list<int> :: iterator it1 = g.begin();
    list<int> :: iterator it2 = --g.end();
    list<int> :: iterator sredina = g.begin();
    advance(sredina, (distance(it1,it2))/2);
    for(it1; it1 != sredina; it1++){

        swap(*it1, *it2);

        it2--;
    }
    if(distance(it1,it2)%2!=0){
        swap(*it1,*it2);
    }
    return g;
}

int main()
{
    list <int> lista1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        lista1.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << "Lista u originalnom redoslijedu" << endl; //List in original order
    ispis(lista1);
    cout << endl;

    list<int> lista2 = zamijeni(lista1);
    cout << "Lista u obrnutom redoslijedu" << endl; //This one is List in the reverse order
    ispis(lista2);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Lista ponovno okrenuta pomocu funkcijskog objekta" << endl; //This one is reversing the list with a function object
    Okreni okreni;
    list<int> lista3 = okreni(lista2);
    ispis(lista3);
    return 0;
}
```

So this is how far I got. I have to create an STL list of integers, using two iterators (one moving forward, the other backward (the sheet defines a bidirectional iterator!)) and a while loop. I have to rotate the order of the elements in the list.
(Also makingsure the solution works for an even and odd number of list elements, and i'm allowed to use the swap algorithm to replace the elements). I have to print the list before and after.
At the end I need to create a function object implemented using a class that will revert the list to its original order, and then print the list to the screen.
As you can see I managed to do the most of my task, but I have trouble with using the while loop instead of for. So I was wondering if you guys could give me some pointers on what should I do with the while loop and if I did something wrong in my task. Thank you all!

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What "trouble"? Please explain clearly. What should the output be? What happens instead? Also, you should pass either by `const&` (if not modifying) or non-const `&` (if modifying), instead of passing by value and wastefully copying in all cases. That'll at best slow you down a lot. At worst, it'll mean modifications don't escape the function and you get confused. C++ passes by value by default, so you need to tell it to pass by reference.

Comment: which loop? Here you can see that any for loop can be written as a while loop: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: Hi, sorry. When I did my task like this my professor said that I didn't use the while loops like I had to in the task that he gave. So instead of `for(it1; it1 != sredina; it1++)` i have to put a while loop.

Comment: That sounds like an artificially fussy way of complicating a task for no real benefit, but hey! The link posted by @idclev463035818 will show you how you can convert `for` to `while`.

Answer (score 0):

well, think about how the for differs from the while loop:

`for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i)`

vs

`while (booleanCondition == true)`

the for loop will do three (non-mandatory) operations:

1. declare a integer variable 'i', that will have the scope of the for
   itself
2. testing the exit condition
3. define an operation to be run after the cycle ends

The three operations a in a for loop are defined inside the for loop, so that we can rewrite it like: `for (A;B;C)`

Why non mandatory? Because it is valid to write an empty (and endless) for loop like this:
`for(;;)` that at that point can only be interrupted by an explicit break inside the code:

```
int k = 0;
for(;;) {
  k = makeKEqualSevenAtSomePoint();
  if (k == 7)
    break;
}
```

Please note: this is usually NOT considered a good approach, as defining an infinite loop, usually is not advisable.

If we take into consideration the `while` loop instead, we find that we only have 1 operation to be defined, and that is the exit condition from the loop:
`while(condition)` which is the condition B in the for loop (`1 < 100` in the example)

So if you need to transform a for into a while, you need to specify the two points A and C:

```
int i = 0;        // declaration A
while (i < 100) { // condition B
  ++i;            // post cycle operation C, implemented in the cycle for the while
}

std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

For your example, without going into the details of the implementation, the conversion between for and while loop would be from this:

```
for(it1; it1 != sredina; ++it1){ // this can be rewritten as:
                                 // for(; it1 != sredina; ++it1), as you
                                 // already declared it1, outside of the for loop
    swap(*it1, *it2);

    it2--;
}
```

to this:

```
while(it1 != sredina){

    swap(*it1, *it2);

    --it2;
    ++it1;
}
```

Please note, although you can assume your compiler will optimize it for you, usually you want to use preincrement and not postincrement, as postincrement is less efficient than preincrement (more here: https://medium.com/better-programming/stop-using-i-in-your-loops-1f906520d548 )